# 'onClick' event not firing first time button click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-side, dom-events

Gridview has buttons for each row like delete/edit button. Those buttons are binded with client side methods (onClick), no more server side methods.

Problem is, when I click first time, button is not firing the client side method, But when I click second time its working..

This is not acutally brower issue. Because, I have checked with all browers. Not working.

Codes: 
I have binded this attribute under gridview xx_RowDataBound method.

```
ibCancel.Attributes["OnClick"] = "javascript: return CancelAdminExtension('" + hidRemarks.ClientID + "','" + bPastExtension + "','" + hidDelRecNr.ClientID + "','" + hidRecNr.Value + "','" + hidDelPurpose.ClientID + "','" + hidPurpose.Value + "');";
```

Javascript method:

```
function CancelAdminExtension(strPurposeID, strPastExtension, strDelRecNr, strRecNr, strDelPurpose, strPurpose) {
  try
  {
      //some logic here

      hidDelRecNr.value = strRecNr;
      hidDelPurpose.value = strPurpose;

      return true;
  }
  catch(err)
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Please suggest any idea to solve this issue.

Sorry, this question may duplicate other questions, I couldn't find the solution to solve my issue.

Comment: do you see any javascript error at the right bottom corner of the status bar of the browser when you click first time or when the page is loaded first time?

Comment: No, I didn't get any errors. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need `javascript: ` prefix in your event handler, moreover afaik it is not a valid syntax.

Comment: but as he said, it's working second time !

Comment: Hi Adrei, I have already checked as you suggested, No luck. Thanks

Comment: Try writing this..ibCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick","return CancelAdminExtension('" + hidRemarks.ClientID + "','" + bPastExtension + "','" + hidDelRecNr.ClientID + "','" + hidRecNr.Value + "','" + hidDelPurpose.ClientID + "','" + hidPurpose.Value + "')");

Comment: can you put a `console.log(err)` or `alert("err)` in the `catch` block, maybe it is throwing an exception the first time you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void uxCustomGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                           

           LinkButton uxEditLinkButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("uxEditLinkButton");
           uxEditLinkButton.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("return doEdit({0})", item.ID);      
        }
    }
```

Does the first click have some reactions?
Usually, I use the code below to bind client events on the back end.

Or you can just test onclick event use a easy alert function.

Answer (score 0):

try using once **Attributes.Add("onclick", "script")**
instead of Attributes["OnClick"]

```
ibCancel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return(CancelAdminExtension('" + hidRemarks.ClientID + "','" + bPastExtension + "','" + hidDelRecNr.ClientID + "','" + hidRecNr.Value + "','" + hidDelPurpose.ClientID + "','" + hidPurpose.Value + "'));");
```

Comment: It seems my code is correct, Let me check my whole code again.. Thank you friends..